# Парсер на python'e после перехода на вторую страницу молчит

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

Доброго времени суток! 
Возникла такая проблема: парсер должен собирать данные из таблицы со второй страницы, ссылку он берет с первой страницы, но вначале всё работает, а вот после перехода на вторую страницу парсер молчит.
Собственно сам код:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from lxml.html import fromstring
from lxml.etree import XMLSyntaxError

URL_BASE = 'https://1xbet.kz/'
URL = 'https://1xbet.kz/live/Football/'
ITEM_PATH = '.game_content_line .dashboard .c-events__item .c-events__item'
SECOND_PATH = '.db-stats__bottom .db-stats__bottom-table'
#по ссылке на таблицу данные разбиты на 3 отдельных div'а, что 
#для меня затрудняет получение данных
THIRD_PATH = '.db-sport__score .db-sport__score-con'



def check_time(stime):
    minutes, seconds = stime.split(':')
    seconds = int(seconds) + (int(minutes) * 60)
    return seconds <= (59 * 60)


def parse_bets():
    f = urlopen(URL)
    list_html = f.read().decode('utf-8')
    list_doc = fromstring(list_html)

    for elem in list_doc.cssselect(ITEM_PATH):
        span = elem.cssselect('span')[0]
        timer = span.text
        if (not timer) or (not check_time(timer)):
            continue


        a = elem.cssselect('a')[0]
        href = a.get('href')
        url = urljoin(URL_BASE, href)
        bets = {'time': timer, 'url': url}
        #print(bets)
        #здесь выводит переменную bets 

        #после этой строки парсер не работает
        details_html = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
        try:
            details_doc = fromstring(details_html)
        except XMLSyntaxError:
            continue

        for details_elem in details_doc.cssselect(SECOND_PATH):
            divis = details_elem.cssselect('div')[0]
            diviz = divis.text

            print(diviz)

            #print(bets)
            #а вот здесь не выводит переменную bets


def main():
    parse_bets()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Хотелось бы узнать в чём причина, ведь парсер может отработать более 40 секунд и не выдать каких-либо данных.

Может ли быть ошибкой то, что я неправильно запрашиваю данные если они в HTML коде написаны так:

```
<div class="db-stats-table__group">
    <div class="db-stats-table__count">
        <script type="jsv#4809^"></script>
        2
        <script type="jsv#4809^"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="db-stats-table__description">Угловые</div>
    <div class="db-stats-table__count">
        <script type="jsv#4810^"></script>
        2
        <script type="jsv#4810^"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Но мне хотелось бы знать почему весь мой код не работает в целом, я плохо в этом разбираюсь, поэтому не знаю что я могу здесь вырезать чтобы было понятно в чем суть моей проблемы

Comment: details_doc.cssselect(SECOND_PATH) имеет длину 0, поэтому цикл не выполняется. Какое значение вы пытаетесь получить со страницы?

Comment: @ivan_susanin там есть таблица с такими данными как Угловые, процент владения мячом и так далее, а если я поменяю SECOND_PATH = '.db-stats__bottom .db-stats__bottom-table .db-stats-table__group' ?

Comment: @hackeevo всё не так просто, искомый фрагмент находится в блоке <script id="liveTabloTMPL" type="text/x-jsrender">, это jquery шаблон. Т.е. неплохо было бы отрендерить, а уже за тем отдать в cssselect

Comment: спасибо за объяснения, а как можно "отрендерить" фрагмент?

Comment: этот кусочек появляется когда жмёшь на треугольник? значит надо нажать на треугольник, и потом искать в дом дереве. Возможно имеет смысл посмотреть в сторону selenium. Задача сводится к выполнению js-кода средствами python

Comment: то есть нельзя вытащить данные не выполняя js-код?

Comment: можно использовать регулярные выражения, например, или искать нужные совпадения последовательно перебирая строки. Только к коду в вопросе это не имеет отношения. В вопросе речь о DOM-дереве) Но я подозреваю, что без js-кода вы будете получать что-то вроде "{^{:dopTabloStat^corners^val1}}" вместо цифр, если вы конечно их ищите.